# TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I'm using a chron job like using schedule.
This is my code

```
import schedule  
import time  

def rank():  
    import new_user as nu  
    nu.new_user()  
    print('successfully loaded')  
    return  

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(rank())  

while 1:  
    schedule.run_pending()  
    time.sleep(1)
```

whenever I run this code I'm getting an error message as follows:

```
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Comment: It should be `schedule.every(5).minutes.do(rank)` (without the parrntheses).

Comment: I tried but then I'm getting an error message as  "TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() >= NoneType()"

Answer (score 4):

replace `rank()` with `rank` in [`do`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Job.do) method invocation

```
import schedule  
import time  

def rank():  
    import new_user as nu  
    nu.new_user()  
    print('successfully loaded')  
    return  

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(rank)  

while 1:  
    schedule.run_pending()  
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I tried but then I'm getting an error message as  "TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() >= NoneType()"

Comment: it is another question and you need to share `new_user` function code

Comment: when I run the code without scheduler, it is working fine and I'm getting the desired output.

Comment: add code without scheduler to question and also provide code for `new_user`